# SwiftUI: How to Call a Function when Photo Picker Closes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using a photo picker in my SwiftUI class to load photos and videos into an array.  Right now I'm displaying those images after they've been selected in the picker.  Works fine.

Instead, I'd like to run a function when I click the "Add" button and upload the objects in that array to Cloudinary for processing and storage.  I can manually make this happen with a separate button outside the picker, but for the best UX, I think this function should run automatically when that "Add" button is selected.

How do I run a function when that "Add" button is clicked?  Do I need to check if the array is not empty and some other condition exists instead?

Here's an image of the picker:
[image]

Here's the picker code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct PhotoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
typealias UIViewControllerType = PHPickerViewController

@ObservedObject var mediaItems: PickedMediaItems
var didFinishPicking: (_ didSelectItems: Bool) -> Void

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
    var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
    config.filter = .any(of: [.images, .videos, .livePhotos])
    config.selectionLimit = 0
    config.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
    
    let controller = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
    controller.delegate = context.coordinator
    return controller
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
    
}


func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(with: self)
}


class Coordinator: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    var photoPicker: PhotoPicker
    
    init(with photoPicker: PhotoPicker) {
        self.photoPicker = photoPicker
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        photoPicker.didFinishPicking(!results.isEmpty)
        
        guard !results.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        for result in results {
            let itemProvider = result.itemProvider
            
            guard let typeIdentifier = itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers.first,
                  let utType = UTType(typeIdentifier)
            else { continue }
            
            if utType.conforms(to: .image) {
                self.getPhoto(from: itemProvider, isLivePhoto: false)
            } else if utType.conforms(to: .movie) {
                self.getVideo(from: itemProvider, typeIdentifier: typeIdentifier)
            } else {
                self.getPhoto(from: itemProvider, isLivePhoto: true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func getPhoto(from itemProvider: NSItemProvider, isLivePhoto: Bool) {
        let objectType: NSItemProviderReading.Type = !isLivePhoto ? UIImage.self : PHLivePhoto.self
        
        if itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: objectType) {
            itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: objectType) { object, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                if !isLivePhoto {
                    if let image = object as? UIImage {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.photoPicker.mediaItems.append(item: PhotoPickerModel(with: image))
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if let livePhoto = object as? PHLivePhoto {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.photoPicker.mediaItems.append(item: PhotoPickerModel(with: livePhoto))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func getVideo(from itemProvider: NSItemProvider, typeIdentifier: String) {
        itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: typeIdentifier) { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            guard let url = url else { return }
            
            let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
            guard let targetURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent) else { return }
            
            do {
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: targetURL.path) {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: targetURL)
                }
                
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: targetURL)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.photoPicker.mediaItems.append(item: PhotoPickerModel(with: targetURL))
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ‘How do I run a function when that "Add" button is clicked?’ You're already doing it. When the user taps “Add”, the picker calls your `picker(_:didFinishPicking:)` method.

Comment: @robmayoff how do I make a state (Published, Observed, etc.) equal to whether or not didFinishPicking is true or false?  I'd like to check that state in the base view that calls the photo picker.

Comment: @robmayoff I figured it out.  Thanks for the help.  I'll write up an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this class to the View:

```
class PickerStatus: ObservableObject {
    var status: Bool = false
}
```

Then added this line to the PhotoPicker:

```
@ObservedObject var finishedSelection: PickerStatus
```

Then in the Coordinator, I added this:

```
for result in results {
                
     self.photoPicker.finishedSelection.status = true

...
}
```

Now in my View I can set the instance of the ObservedObject, pass it into my child views including the PhotoPicker and check the value of that same Observed Object:

```
@ObservedObject var finishedSelection = PickerStatus()
```